# local storage not save value

Tags: angular, local-storage, ionic4

I want to store my checked radio button in local storage from returning data from Ionic 4 Modal . when l click on any radio button to change value initial and reload page l got same value not saving in local storage

```
export class Tab1Page {
    weather:any;
    cities = 'Muscat'

    constructor(private https: HttpClient,public popoverController: PopoverController
      ,public nav : NavController,public modalController: ModalController,
      private storage: Storage ) {
        this.test()
    }

    async test (){
        this.https.get('weather/'+this.cities+'.json')
      .subscribe(data => {
            this.weather = data
        })



    }


    async openUserModal() {

        const modal = await this.modalController.create({
            component: PopoverstationsPage,
        });

        await modal.present();
        modal.onDidDismiss().then((r) => {

            console.log("the result:", r , 'test'+ this.cities);
            this.cities = r.data.result

            this.test()
            this.storage.set('cities',this.cities)

            this.storage.get('cities',this.cities).then((val) => {
                console.log('Your city is', val);
            });     

        });

    }
```

Comment: You are calling `this.test()` in onDidDismiss... This seems to reset your `this.cities` value. Also `this.storage.set` is also asynchronous

Comment: I have to call 'this.cities' in onDismiss , even when user change city from modal page model page will return data for city he is choice then show information .

Comment: @SurajRao any solution please ?

Comment: As I said `storage.set` is asynchronous. Do `await this.storage.set`...

Comment: or `this.storage.set(...).then(()=>//get from storage here)`

Comment: both tried failed

Comment: is it logging in onDidDismiss?

Comment: @SurajRao if l put     `await  this.storage.set('cities',this.cities)` inside `onDidDismiss` l get error under `await` `'await' expression is only allowed within an async function.ts` so l have to put it out of `onDidDismiss` then l test second code `this.storage.set(...).then(()=>` inside  `onDidDismiss` l get same problem he doesnt save value , when l reload page l get same value for `cities` is muscat . what do you think it is cause initial for cities in top of code ?

Comment: in constructor check if value is in local storage and set cities from there if exists. or use an angular lifecycle if you want on reloading page

Comment: when i run home page  l have  initial value for cities it is muscat loaded in url json . when l come to change city for first time l and data is reload for new city l get in console same  initial value for cities it is muscat not change for new value . so l need back again to change city l will got new value l choice in console